# How to convert String to Time and insert it MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, time

I have a JSP page, so the user can insert the time when he/she arrives and goes from the place manually.
My question is: how can I convert that String, from the input box (JSP) to then insert it to query thus into my MySQL table.
I am using Java - servlet.
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse a [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) in the given pattern to a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object.

Assuming that it's `HH:mm`, then you can do so:

```
String time = request.getParameter("time");
Date date = null;

try {
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(time);
}
catch (ParseException e) {
    request.setAttribute("time_error", "Please enter time in format HH:mm");
}
```

Once having the [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object, you can store it in a `TIME` column by converting it to [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) and using [`PreparedStatement#setTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTime%28int,%20java.sql.Time%29).

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tablename (columname) VALUES (?)");
preparedStatement.setTime(1, new Time(date.getTime()));
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Only one thing. I'm trying to create the Date Object and I'm receiving a compiling error. "Reference to Date is ambiguous, both class. ... match.

Comment: Don't use `java.sql.Date`. Use `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Thanks, I've solved. As I am using in the same package .sql.Date and util.Date I had to specify which type of data I was passing as a parameter. So I used (String s, java.uitl.Date clockIn ...). It saolved the problem. Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest to do it the other way round. The `java.sql.Date` is very rarely to be used anyway. You basicaly only need it in the `PreparedStatement#setDate()` method, nowhere else.